# Get folder name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some string, which is some path C:\A\B\C\D\
How can I get the folder name, say "A" or "B" or other needed.
I have solution only for "D":

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f %%i IN ("C:\A\B\C\D\") DO (
set parent=%%~dpi
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ("!parent:~0,-1!") do echo %%~nf
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear ("other folder needed" is *not* a specification) so I *assumed* you want to separate all folders into array elements, so any desired folder can be get via its index.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=C:\A\B\C\D\"

rem Separate all folders in the string into "folder" array
set i=-1
for %%a in ("%string:\=" "%") do (
   if %%a neq "" (
      set /A i+=1
      set "folder[!i!]=%%~a"
   )
)

rem Show some folders
echo The first folder:  %folder[1]%
echo The second folder: %folder[2]%
echo The last folder:   !folder[%i%]!
```

For further details on arrays in Batch files, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: unfortunately it strips "!" from folder names

Answer (score 2):

Next code snippet splits a string to substrings delimited with the `\` backslash character. Works with or without a trailing backslash,  with or without blank space(s) in a string (path). Note proper quoting in `set` commands:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

set "fullpath=C:\Aa\B b\Cc\D d\"
set "to_parse="%fullpath:\=" "%""

for %%G in (%to_parse%) do (
  echo %%~G       %%G
)
```

**Output**:

```
==>30285354.bat
C:       "C:"
Aa       "Aa"
B b       "B b"
Cc       "Cc"
D d       "D d"
       ""

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)